# How I can be good Asp.Net Developer Freelancer

Tags: freelance-websites, attracting-clients, portfolio

I've done about 2.5 years of certification course from Aptech. And now I want to be a good freelancer for freelancing sites like Odesk and Elance. I've made my profile on that but the actual problem is that that I've only basic understanding of web development and on these sites there are lot of competition with more experience and low price bid.

Now I'm in a fix, how can I make a good reputation on these sites to make my future in this industry?
I want to work from home as a web developer. But I've no professional experience on making a big projects. I've made small projects during my course. And my interest is in Asp.net web development.
Any suggestions and ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

- Each of this two sites have a sort of ability tests which you can use in building a good first impression. If you have theoretical knowledge, than you should score high. By doing this, you will gain edge (things will get easier).
- Start small with small steps. Don't aim high (you risk losing optimism and enthusiasm). Do your bidding for small projects.
- Make time and create a personal webpage and some sort of on-line presence (LinkedIn profile,  etc.)
- Don't wait to be chosen. Hustle on both websites. You need to bid as many times as possible and when you do so, make sure your offer is hard to be dismissed.
- Do some "community" work. Find a project or a non-profit organisation for which you can serve with enthusiasm and responsibility. This will help build a real-life experience.
- Don't expect immediate results. It takes time and hard work.

Answer (score 1):

There is not easy bred. You start with simple tasks, crumbles, and with growing experience start taking larger projects.

Also it's advisable you build your own website firstly since building it you will face a lot of things you will later meet in another projects.